# Spring boot web integration test fail when has two postForEntity in one test method with same request body?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, integration-testing

Spring boot project , when did web integration test encountered a problem, very strange. Business logic is easy, just statistics reservation count.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/plus1",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> addReservation(@RequestBody ReservationDTO dto){
    logger.info("{} plus 1", dto.getName());
    //check if has plused
    Reservation reservation = reservationDao.findByNameAndCreatedDate(dto.getName(),LocalDate.now());
    if(reservation != null){
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(String.format("%s %s has reserved", dto.getName(),LocalDate.now().toString()));
    }
    //if today not reserved plus one
    Reservation entity = BeanMapper.map(dto, Reservation.class);
    entity.setCreatedDate(LocalDate.now());
    reservationDao.save(entity);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(entity);
}
```

Web integration test:

```
@Test
public void test_repeat_add_reservation(){
    String add_reservation_url = String.format(add_reservation_url_format, port);
    ReservationDTO dto = new ReservationDTO();
    dto.setName("foo");
    dto.setComment("bar");
    new TestRestTemplate().postForEntity(add_reservation_url, dto , Reservation.class);
    new TestRestTemplate().postForEntity(add_reservation_url, dto , Reservation.class);
}
```

when execute this test, it has below exception:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Unrecognized token 'foo': was expecting 'null', 'true', 'false' or NaN
at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@51b87df7; line: 1, column: 5]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'foo': was expecting 'null', 'true', 'false' or NaN
at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@51b87df7; line: 1, column: 5]
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:224)
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:208)
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:95)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:835)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:819)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:599)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:557)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:384)
```

Why if has two `postForEntity` continuously with same request object, it will throw exception?
Now I changed the code a little, it is ok now.

```
    ReservationDTO dto = new ReservationDTO();
    dto.setName("foo");
    dto.setComment("bar");
    new TestRestTemplate().postForEntity(add_reservation_url, dto , Reservation.class);
    dto.setName("foo2");
    new TestRestTemplate().postForEntity(add_reservation_url, dto , Reservation.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a stupid mistake.

```
new TestRestTemplate().postForEntity(add_reservation_url, dto , Reservation.class);
new TestRestTemplate().postForEntity(add_reservation_url, dto , Reservation.class);
```

}

Because the second post only return

```
return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(String.format("%s %s has reserved", dto.getName(),LocalDate.now().toString()));
```

So second post should change to

```
new TestRestTemplate().postForEntity(add_reservation_url, dto , String.class);
```